# Why isn't this javascript guessing game running correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create this psychic game where the program essentially chooses and random letter and the user has 9 guesses to try and guess the random letter.

I feel like so much of the code that I wrote isn't being recognized and I'm feeling very lost and confused.

This is what I have so far.

Basically I expect that the guesses should be displaying and going down every time the user doesn't correctly guess the letter, and when the user tries 9 times, the losses go up.

When I run it though, the only thing that happens is the letters get stored in the array.

```js
var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guesses = 9;
var computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
var userGuessSoFar = [];

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
  var userGuess = event.key;
  document.getElementById("guess-so-far").textContent = userGuess;
  if (userGuess == computerGuess) {
    wins++;
  } else {
    guesses--;
    userGuessSoFar.push(userGuess);
    document.getElementById("guess-so-far").textContent = userGuessSoFar;
  }
  updateWins();
  updateGuesses();
  updateLosses();
}
if (userGuessSoFar.length > 8) {
  losses++;
  userGuessSoFar = [];
  guesses = 9;
  updateLosses();
}

function updateWins() {
  var winPoints = document.getElementById("wins").textContent;
  updateWins.textContent = wins;
}

function updateGuesses() {
  var guessesLeft = document.getElementById("guessLeft").textContent;
  updateGuesses.textContent = guesses;
}

function updateLosses() {
  var losePoints = document.getElementById("losses").textContent;
  updateLosses.textContent = losses;
}
```

```html
<h1>Psychic Game</h1>
<h2>Guess what letter I'm thinking of...</h2>
<p>Wins: </p><span id="wins"></span>
<p>Losses: <span id="losses"></span></p>
<p>Guesses Left: </p><span id="guessLeft"></span>
<p>Your guesses so far: </p><span id="guess-so-far"></span>
```

Comment: What is your console telling you?

Comment: Here's a shortcut to get the alphabet into an array: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");`

Comment: @EliRichardson Or how about `[...Array(26)].map((a,b)=>String.fromCharCode(b+97))` :P

Comment: @EliRichardson, Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JosephMarikle Wow! I love the conciseness of that. (For real though that's pretty neat)

Comment: @JosephMarikle that's pretty inefficient compared to the String.split() method...

Comment: @EliRichardson _"Here's a shortcut to get the alphabet into an array: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");`"_ - and here's a shortcut to provide the alphabet in a way that is accessible via a zero-based index: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` ;-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access

Comment: @LucaKiebel lol.  Not a serious suggestion.  It's overkill for sure, but it was fun to write.  The *only* advantage I can think of is that it reduces the chance of typos resulting in hard-to-find logic errors (mistyping or forgetting a letter).

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple immediate issues:

1. The part that checks `userGuessSoFar` should be inside the `onkeyup` handler.
2. The "update" functions each define a variable that is the `textContent` of an element. But a different variable (which is actually the name of the function) is set to the string value.

Here are a few optimizations:

1. As long as you are defining global variables, there's no need to define the "update" display elements every time the values are refreshed.
2. I also implemented the comment suggestion from @EliRichardson, a shorter way to define an alphabet array.
3. Also implemented suggestion from @LucaKiebel to call the display functions on first run.
4. Updated the "win" logic to reset the guesses and choose a new letter.
5. Combined all display updaters into one function.

```js
var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("");
var wins = 0;
var losses = 0;
var guesses = 9;
var computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
var userGuessSoFar = [];
var winPoints = document.getElementById("wins");
var guessesLeft = document.getElementById("guessLeft");
var losePoints = document.getElementById("losses");
var guessSoFar = document.getElementById("guess-so-far");

function updateDisplays() {
  winPoints.textContent = wins;
  guessesLeft.textContent = guesses;
  losePoints.textContent = losses;
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {

  var userGuess = event.key;
  userGuessSoFar.push(userGuess);
  guessSoFar.textContent = userGuessSoFar;

  if (userGuess == computerGuess) {

    wins++;
    guesses = 9
    userGuessSoFar = [];
    computerGuess = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

  } else {

    guesses--;

    if (guesses == 0) {
      losses++;
      userGuessSoFar = [];
      guesses = 9;
    }

  }

  updateDisplays();

}


updateDisplays();
```

```html
<p>Guess what letter I'm thinking of...</p>
Wins: <span id="wins"></span><br>
Losses: <span id="losses"></span><br>
Guesses Remaining: <span id="guessLeft"></span>
<p>Guesses: <span id="guess-so-far"></span></p>
```

Comment: Nice, but maybe run the update functions once when the game starts (so you have all the starting values displayed)

Comment: So much cleaner than what I have! Thanks for all the suggestions.